# AnalogClock and DigitalClock views are missing in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

I am learning android development with the tutorial on YouTube. The guy there has AnalogClock and DigitalClock but I do not have it as you can see it:

[image]

How can I add that to my android studio?

Answer (score 0):

DigitalClock is deprecated since API 17 and AnalogClock is deprecated since API 23, so setting your project above any of those API levels will supress the possibility to use them.

You can lower your max API under 17, but I'm quite sure that you don't want the side effects of that choice.

So, if you need a clock but your project needs to cover modern APIs you have several alternatives:

- Copy source code from old Android source code in order to reimplement yourself the older AnalogClock or DigitalClock classes.
- Search for a 3rd party clock class.
- Use and customize yourself a [TextClock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html).